# Unable to connect to the route in ajax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been working on a laravel app. gonna go down to the problem straight... I have a like button which triggers the function likeit() in JS. In this function there is AJAX call which was suppose to send the post_id which is liked to the function postLikePost where it will execute the query.
Now for checking purpose since my route wasnt working... I linked the url to custom file like
url: 'addlike.php'

added db connection and mysqli query and it works fine. But I wanna go with the flow and want to do it through the controller and stuff.

Here is my AJAX Call:

```
    function like_function(post_id){
var urlLike = "{{ route('like') }}";
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
             method: 'POST',
             url: urlLike,
             data: {post_id: post_id},
             success: function(response)
             {
                alert(response);
             }
          });
```

My controller Where I want to add the postLikePost function

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Post::orderBy('post_id','desc')->get();
        return view('home',['data'=>$data]);
    }
    public function postLikePost(){
        return "wow";
    }
}

       }
```

my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/login','MainController@index');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/like',[
    'uses' => 'HomeController@postLikePost',
    'as' => 'like',
]);
```

Comment: Is your JS inline (in Blade) or in an external .js file? What errors do you get in console? How do you call your `like_function()`?

Comment: @kerbholz the like function is in the main blade file... not in external js, and is triggered using the onclick command